# Usage of web browsers among programmers

Tags: browser

I am trying to build a web application in HTML5 aimed at programmers, so it is important that I know the percentage of programmers that won't use our site (because of Internet Explorer).  I've searched around the web and have found no good statistics.  Do any of you guys know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no programmers use IE, or if they do, they have also other browsers on their systems. I study @ electronics department and within my classmates, using IE for not-testing purposes is a shame.

But thats only 19-25 age range, you need more data for statistics ;)

Comment: thank you for helping.  anyone else with more of an age range?